# How to exclude table names while importing all existing table names

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get all table names in db, It is working fine but just want to exclude or ignore migrations, user, password_resets and any other default table names. I know it can be done by filtering result array, but wondering if there is any eloquent ready to use function for this situation.

```
        $tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
```

Answer (score 0):

The most possible generic way to is probably this:

```
$database = config("database.connections.".config('database.default').".database");
$in = "Tables_in_".$database;
$tables = DB::select("SHOW TABLES 
   WHERE {$in} <> 'migrations' 
     AND {$in} <> 'password_resets'
     AND {$in} <> 'users'
");
```

Comment: Undefined variable: in

Comment: What does `dd($in);` give you? It should show a string something like `Tables_in_database_name`

Comment: Maybe your config is different than standard. Puzzling. You have anything from `dd(config('database'));` ?

Comment: Oh I got you know, actully I am not using $database = config("database.connections.".config('database.default').".database");   this part

Comment: because $tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES'); this command just get the tables for me without using any $database = config("");

Comment: Do you want me to use that config thing for purpose? I mean is that the trick ?

Comment: Not really the trick. I don't know the name of your database, So that's why I get it from the config. The given SQL omits the tables you don't want in the array result.

Comment: Just copy/past the code I offered, the 3 lines, and run it. The $in is in use in the SQL.